# ItemUpdating event on DocumentSet

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, event-receiver, document-set

[;]

We have a document-set the event receiver is attached to the ContentType (for Document-Set), the idea is when a new site is created document-Set is created as part of provisioning and the event is attached to the it. We tried attaching event-receiver using ([typical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076660/updating-already-deployed-sharepoint-content-types-to-handle-additional-item-eve)) PS script. We can see the event-receiver attached in the SP Manager as well as the (event receiver) count.

The problem is Event receiver (itemupdated) does not trigger when user adds/updates the document within the document-Set.

Eventreceiver triggers when we try to modify documentSet metadata/fields, and when we attach it directly to the list instead of documentSet. The [documentSet wraps the class](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/8b3ff1c6-860c-467d-a58d-608059020cad/attaching-event-receivers-to-document-sets?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious) SPFolder so the add/edit document will not trigger the itemUpdated event? Is there any event for when document is added/updated from the documentSet? What am I missing here?

Any pointers will be great help.

regards,

[;]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add event handlers for each content type that can be stored in the document set that you want to handle the events for.  For example, if your document set, holds 'Document' content types, you need to add event handlers for the 'Document' content type.

You have attached an event handler to the document set, but not the documents within the document set.